# Как получить данные с callback_data?

Tags: python, telebot, python-telegram-bot

Имеется тестовое задание: сделать бота для крупной торговой площадки для всей страны. Также присутствует главное меню в виде KeyboardButton, в котором отображен каталог города, который выбрал юзер. По стандарту пользователя встречает приветствие, а потом уже выбор города. Изначально у пользователя стоит город "Москва". И в главном меню он отображается. Чтобы сменить город и пользователя есть кнопка также в главном меню, и когда он на нее нажимает, бот высылает сообщение в виде InlineKeyboardButton с городами возможными для продажи/покупки. Как мне сделать так, чтобы название города менялось в меню, когда юзер выбирал через кнопку InlineKeyboardButton, или по другому. Как мне получить данные полученные от callback_data(InlineKeyboardButton) в виде переменной, чтобы подставлять ее в название города и он автоматически менял название в меню?

Буду очень благодарен за оказанную помощь!

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('None')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start']) # Объвление команды старт
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton ('Изм.город')
    item2 = types.KeyboardButton('Каталог')
    item3 = types.KeyboardButton('Отзывы и правила')
    item4 = types.KeyboardButton('Оператор')
    item5 = types.KeyboardButton('Профиль')
    item6 = types.KeyboardButton('Назад')
    markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5,item6)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '<b>Приветствуем вас в барахолке вашего города!\n'
                                      '\n'
                                      'Для выбора города жми "Изм.город".\n'
                                      '\n'
                                      'Удачных покупок</b>', parse_mode="html", reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def bot_message(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == 'Изм.город':
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
            bnt1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Ангарск', callback_data="Angarsk")
            bnt2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Владивосток', callback_data="Vladik")
            bnt3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Екатеринбург', callback_data="Ekater")
            bnt4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Казань', callback_data="Kazan")
            bnt5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Москва', callback_data="Moskva")
            bnt6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Новосибирск', callback_data="Nsk")
            bnt7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Оренбург', callback_data='Orenburg')
            bnt8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Самара', callback_data="Samara")
            bnt9 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Саратов', callback_data="Saratow")
            bnt10 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Томск', callback_data="Toms")
            bnt11 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Уфа', callback_data="Ufa")
            bnt12 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Челябинск', callback_data="Chlb")
            bnt13 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Архангельск', callback_data="Arhan")
            bnt14 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Воронеж', callback_data="Voronez")
            bnt15 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Иркутск', callback_data="Irkutsk")
            bnt16 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Красноярск', callback_data="Krasnoayrsk")
            bnt17 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Нижний Новгород', callback_data="NN")
            bnt18 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Омск', callback_data="Oms")
            bnt19 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Ростов на Дону', callback_data="RnD")
            bnt20 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Санкт-Петербург', callback_data="SPB")
            bnt21 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Тверь', callback_data="Tver")
            bnt22 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Тюмень', callback_data="Tumen")
            bnt23 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Хабаровск', callback_data="Habarovsk")
            bnt24 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Чита', callback_data="Chita")
            btnotmena = types.InlineKeyboardButton ('Отмена', callback_data='Otmena')
            markup.add(bnt1,bnt2, bnt3, bnt4, bnt5,bnt6,bnt7,bnt8,bnt9,bnt10,bnt11,bnt12,bnt13,bnt14,bnt15,bnt16,bnt17,bnt18,bnt19,bnt20,bnt21,bnt22,bnt23,bnt24)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '<b>⚡️ Выберите интересующий вас город:</b>', parse_mode="html", reply_markup=markup)
    if message.text == 'Каталог':

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы изменять данные, вам необходимо где-то их хранить. Для этого стоит воспользоваться базой данных - https://habr.com/ru/articles/552788/ (полезная ссылка).

---

А чтобы получать callback_data вам надо обрабатывать нажатие на кнопку и использовать `CallbackQueryHandler` . Советую прочитать, возможно поможет - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68687141/how-to-get-callback-from-inline-keyboard-telegram